# Admob and facebook mediation IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, admob, facebook-audience-network, mobile-ad-mediation

I have an iOS app on AppStore with admob integration (working good) and I recently implement mediation between Facebook and Admob. Based on the guides available, I have performed the all steps.

I have not made any other change to the app code. To test, I have set very high ecpm for FAN on admob page so that the ads should be served first from FAN and not admob.

To test, I installed my modified app on the phone that already had facebook app installed. Now, I only see admob test ads and no facebook ads.

When I test only facebook ads, I have this message :

```
[FBAudienceNetworkLog/FBAdProvider:135 <error>] Ad request error: Error Domain=com.facebook.ads.sdk Code=1001 "No fill" UserInfo=0x174a7d480 {
    NSLocalizedDescription=No fill,
    FBAdErrorDetailKey = {
        msg = "No fill. We are not able to serve ads to this person. Please refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/faq#a12. If you are integrating Audience Network for the first time, you can use test ads https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/testing.";
    }
}
```

My status on facebook profile for this placement is: `Activated`

I don't understand why I have this message.
Please advise.

Comment: Anyone had this problem or this message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the ad is activated does not mean it will always display an ad.

- You need to have the Facebook app installed and you need to be logged in.
- You have to disable Limit Ad Tracking in the system settings
- Even then it might just not have an ad available.

Comment: Banner Ad With Error : Error Domain=com.google.admob Code=9 "Request Error: No ad to show from all configured ad networks." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Request Error: No ad to show from all configured ad networks.} CODE :: 9, In iPad facebook mediation working well, but iphone getting above error, can you help on this,

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly on middle east app users , as Facebook is a mainly app there. 
It has lower fill rate in USA.